# Jquery Mobile - Disable address bar auto hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, hide, address-bar

Wondering if there's a way to stop Jquery Mobile from auto hiding the address bar. Apparently it does this by default and I've found just one other post pointing to the mechanism. If someone has tackled this already awesome - otherwise I'll find some override and post here. Thanks for ur help!

Comment: +1 from me. I'm getting a really painful delay on the address bar auto hiding, so I was trying to disable it, so I could attempt to get it to fire earlier myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
   $.mobile.useFastClick=false;
 });
```

Because the mobileinit event is triggered immediately upon execution, you'll need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded, so link your files like

```
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Comment: I guess it depends on the version of JQuery Mobile you're using, but I think this feature (useFastClick) has been removed.

Comment: Ah ok yeah - I tried and it didn't work ... so far all I've found is suggestion to pull the function from the jquery mobile js but I'd prefer not to hack the core like that.